# Можно ли сказать, что HTML это подвид xml?

Tags: html, xml

Можно ли сказать, что HTML это подвид XML?

Answer (score 5):

Нет.

Изначально это подвид SGML, но потом и этого не осталось.

Ещё была версия xhtml, вот она была «подвидом» xml, но не прижилась.

Comment: Актуальная спецификация HTML5 определяет [XML-синтаксис](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/xhtml.html) (это не то же самое что старый xhtml, и оно работает в современных браузерах, я проверял), так что в каком-то смысле всё-таки наверное немножко да?

Answer (score 2):

Нет

Год выхода html = 1990

Год выхода xml = 1998

Answer (score -2):

Нет, не надо так говорить. Они для разного нужны.
XML - хранение и передача данных (и в центре - сами данные). HTML - отображение данных (и в центре - то, как они выглядят).

Comment: HTML не определяет отображение данных, за это отвечает CSS

Comment: @andreymal, не согласен - ваше замечание вне контекста дано. Разумеется, он определяет, учитывая, что мы говорим о различии ХML и HTML - он структурирует контент на странице. Напомню, что CSS появился позже, чем HTML, по такой логике получается, что отображения данных вообще не было, когда только HTML был.

Comment: @andreymal, Вот, кстати, ссылка подходящая: <https://msiter.ru/tutorials/uchebnik-xml-dlya-nachinayushchih/chto-takoe-xml#:~:text=%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20XML%20%D0%B8%20HTML&text=%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85,%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82.>

Comment: Да, HTML именно что структурирует. И структурирование не имеет никакого отношения к отображению. За отображение отвечает не HTML, а браузер и встроенные в нём стили (CSS или не CSS — даже не очень важно, в любом случае HTML не имеет отношения к отображению)

Comment: Могу только повторить, что структурирование определяет отображение (да и не один я так считаю). Измените структурирование - изменится отображение => определяет (просто не он один определяет). В контексте обсуждения разницы HTML и браузера замечание имело бы смысл обсуждать, и оно было бы верным, в контесте HTML и ХML - выглядит формальным для меня:-)

Comment: В контексте HTML и XML — раньше существовал XHTML (упомянут в соседнем ответе), сегодня существует [XML-синтаксис для HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/xhtml.html), так что разделение в той формулировке, в которой сформулировали вы, всё равно имеет не очень много смысла

Comment: (вообще в актуальной спецификации HTML5 есть [раздел про рендеринг](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html), но там сразу же в начале сказано, что это всего лишь рекомендации, а не обязательные для исполнения правила)

Comment: Это все верно, но это всё детали следующего порядка пока действует факт: "Измените структурирование - изменится отображение". И дихотомия "хранение и передача против отображения" отвечает на вопрос Руслана лучше, чем "хранение и передача против структурирования", так как ХML тоже структуру содержит (чем, полагаю, и был порождён вопрос).

Comment: HTML без стилей тоже содержит только структуру, отображение определяется в CSS и в браузере. XML тоже можно отобразить, если очень захотеть (разве что общего стандарта для отображения XML нету), и тогда изменение структуры XML тоже будет изменять его отображение, так что в вашей формулировке всё ещё не очень много смысла